# How can I change Max Embed Size in WordPress 3.5?

Tags: embed, media-settings

after updating to WordPress 3.5 my automatic embeds are limited to a width of 500px, and the settings for this size have been removed with WordPress 3.5

Also, I can't find the Values in the `wp_options` table.

Does anyone know how to change them again?

Cheers,
fischi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the function `wp_embed_defaults()` in `wp-includes/media.php`:

```
function wp_embed_defaults() {
    if ( ! empty( $GLOBALS['content_width'] ) )
        $width = (int) $GLOBALS['content_width'];

    if ( empty( $width ) )
        $width = 500;

    $height = min( ceil( $width * 1.5 ), 1000 );

    return apply_filters( 'embed_defaults', compact( 'width', 'height' ) );
}
```

To change these values filter `embed_defaults`:

```
add_filter( 'embed_defaults', 'wpse_76102_new_embed_size' );

function wpse_76102_new_embed_size()
{
    // adjust these pixel values to your needs
    return array( 'width' => 1000, 'height' => 600 );
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks :) I was looking all all over the options...

Comment: @toscho Do you remember how this was made in v3.4.2? I am asking this as I adjusted my embed size somehow on the previous version and I cannot find any trace of it in my functions/plugin so I am thinking that maybe I edited the core files. I am asking this because I want to remove whichever edit that I did in case it was not the core files. Nonetheless, this is a great answer.

Comment: @ChristineCooper It was the option `embed_size_w`. So a filter on `pre_get_option_embed_size_w` should be a good candidate.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-set-oembed-max-width-in-wordpress-3-5-with-content_width/

Add the below to functions.php

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 600;
```

Then had to go in and re-save the post to make it work.